# What is the role of selector in UILocalizedIndexedCollation's sectionForObject:(id)object collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector method

Tags: iphone, ios, selector

I am a beginner of iOS development and while going through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) document (iOS Developer Guide about configuring a TableView with Indexed List) I came across this:

```
// Listing 4.7
for (State *theState in statesTemp) {
        NSInteger sect = [theCollation sectionForObject:theState collationStringSelector:@selector(name)];
        theState.sectionNumber = sect;
    }
```

I could not figure out the selector (`@selector(name)`) and its purpose, nor could I find the method with the name passed in the selector i.e. `name`. I googled for examples to find a better explanation, and came across [this](http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/230) example.

In the code listing, there is a statement which is a method call:

```
self.tableData = [self partitionObjects:objects collationStringSelector:@selector(title)];
```

now the selector is called `title`. I have not been able to find a better explanation, and my question is what is the purpose of this selector and the method referred by this selector, and what should it do and return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In general

With the `@selector(title:)` you define which method will be called.

in my example it will call

```
- (void) title:(id)someObject {}
```

Be carefull with the semicolon at the end! If you have a semicolon at the end you method will have parameters like mine above.

Your code states just `@selector(title)` and will call a method title without a parameter like this:

```
- (void)title {}
```

## Specific to UILocalizedIndexCollation

The docs state:

> **selector**
>   A selector that identifies a method returning an identifying
>   string for object that is used in collation. The method should take no
>   arguments and return an NSString object. For example, this could be a
>   name property on the object.

So i would suggest you implement it like this

```
self.tableData = [self partitionObjects:objects collationStringSelector:@selector(title)];
 ...
- (NSString *)title {
     NSString *title;
     // some code to fill title with an identifier for your object
     return title;
}
```

Comment: My question is specific to UILocalizedIndexCollation class, I asked what is the purpose of that particular selector passed in sectionForObject:theState collationStringSelector:@selector(name) method and how to implement it

Answer (score -1):

Try replace the `title` with `self`:

```
self.tableData = [self partitionObjects:objects collationStringSelector:@selector(self)];
```

worked for me