# Dynamic selector using UILocalizedIndexedCollation sectionForObject:collationStringSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalizedcollation

I need to set the selector dynamically when using UILocalizedIndexedCollation
In my app, I have the following code:

```
 UILocalizedIndexedCollation *indexedCollation=[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    for (MyObject *theObject in objects)
    {
        NSInteger section;
        section=[indexedCollation sectionForObject:theObject collationStringSelector:@selector(mainTitle)];

        theObject.section=(int)section;
    }
```

mainTitle is one of many properties in myObject.
However, I want the selector to by any string. I followed hint from this site:
 [What is the role of selector in UILocalizedIndexedCollation's sectionForObject:(id)object collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609440/what-is-the-role-of-selector-in-uilocalizedindexedcollations-sectionforobject), and introdused following:

```
-(NSString*)myString
{
    NSString* myString;
    myString = // whatever code to set new string belonging to myObject
    return myString;
}

 section=[indexedCollation sectionForObject:theObject collationStringSelector:@selector(myString)];
```

This caused crash with error: [MyObject myString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

What is the correct way to add a dynamic selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to handle sorting on different properties of `MyObject`.

The error you reported is happening because the `MyString` method needs to be part of the `MyObject` class, not the class using the `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`.

One dynamic way to specific the selector would be something like this:

```
UILocalizedIndexedCollation *indexedCollation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];

NSString *propertyName;
if (someConditionA) {
    propertyName = @"mainTitle";
} else if (someConditionB) {
    propertyName = @"description"; // whatever property you need
} else {
    propertyName = @"name"; // some default property you want to use
}
SEL propertySelector = NSSelectorFromString(propertyName);

for (MyObject *theObject in objects) {
    NSInteger section = [indexedCollation sectionForObject:theObject collationStringSelector:propertySelector];
    theObject.section = section;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using NSSelectorFromString and just have a function that returns a SEL, i.e. @selector(mainTitle), this way you have some protection from the compiler